# finding the intersection of several curves in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting

I have 4 sets of data that try to fit curves on these data. for each of the sets of data, I used a code like below to fit a curve.

```
center_540=np.sort(center_540,axis=0)
y=center_540[itr,:]
x=[0.2 ,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
popt, pcov,info,msg, ier= curve_fit(objective, x, y,full_output=True)
# summarize the parameter values
a, b, c ,d,e,f= popt
# plot input vs output
pyplot.scatter(x, y)
# define a sequence of inputs between the smallest and largest known inputs
x_line = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
# calculate the output for the range
y_line = objective(x_line, a, b, c,d,e,f)
# create a line plot for the mapping function
pyplot.plot(x_line, y_line, '--', color='red')
pyplot.xlabel('Rate')
pyplot.ylabel('PSNR')
err = np.dot(info['fvec'], info['fvec'])
plt.title('interpolation error resolution 540p: err=%f' %err)
pyplot.show()
```

after that, I tried to find the intersection of these curves. for this aim I used the following code that shows the intersection of each of the two curves:

```
find_root(0.0063 , -0.1260 , 1.0146,-4.2147,10.4717,14.9473,0.0179 , -0.3148 , 2.1038,-6.7798,11.6871,15.5829)#1080 vs 720
find_root(0.0063 , -0.1260 , 1.0146,-4.2147,10.4717,14.9473,0.0189 , -0.3332 , 2.2272,-7.1543,12.0520,15.3168)# 1080 vs 540
find_root(0.0063 , -0.1260 , 1.0146,-4.2147,10.4717,14.9473,0.0178 , -0.3181 , 2.1672,-7.0761,11.6511,15.8349)#1080 vs 360
find_root(0.0179 , -0.3148 , 2.1038,-6.7798,11.6871,15.5829,0.0189 , -0.3332 , 2.2272,-7.1543,12.0520,15.3168) # 720 vs 540
find_root( 0.0179 , -0.3148 , 2.1038,-6.7798,11.6871,15.5829,0.0178 , -0.3181 , 2.1672,-7.0761,11.6511,15.8349)#720 vs 360
find_root(0.0189 , -0.3332 , 2.2272,-7.1543,12.0520,15.3168,0.0178 , -0.3181 , 2.1672,-7.0761,11.6511,15.8349)# 540 vs 360
```

the numbers in find_root functions are the values of the polynomial function in curve fitting.
this is the `find_root` function definition:

```
def find_root(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2):
    coeff=[a1-a2,b1-b2,c1-c2,d1-d2,e1-e2,f1-f2]
    print(np.roots(coeff))
```

but when I check the roots using the `find_root` function with the diagram in the first code I see some roots that do not exist in the diagram. what is the problem?
[image]

for example in the diagram we can see the intersections are lower than 1 but when I use find_root function I have these roots that some real roots con not be see in the diagram

```
[ 7.19666881+0.j          4.11941032+2.23825508j  4.11941032-2.23825508j
  1.14334481+0.j         -0.30297219+0.j        ]
[ 7.32487047+0.j          4.13676725+2.34581369j  4.13676725-2.34581369j
  1.01965241+0.j         -0.17361292+0.j        ]
[ 7.48885498+0.j          4.24400787+2.72602922j  4.24400787-2.72602922j
  1.09680306+0.j         -0.36932595+0.j        ]
[8.56875045+0.j         4.40845674+3.11694138j 4.40845674-3.11694138j
 0.50716803+0.89895985j 0.50716803-0.89895985j]
[-47.61740723+0.j           7.2784646 +3.00665406j
   7.2784646 -3.00665406j   0.95450723+0.j
  -0.89402922+0.j        ]
[ 6.88889702+1.76503189j  6.88889702-1.76503189j -0.72213743+2.48208939j
 -0.72213743-2.48208939j  1.39375355+0.j        ]
```

Comment: The fit is fairly poor, so finding the intersection from the lines of fit doesn't make much sense. If you don't show your original data we can't demonstrate how to improve the fit.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following curves:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

c1080 = np.array([0.0063 , -0.1260 , 1.0146, -4.2147, 10.4717, 14.9473])
c720 = np.array([0.0179 , -0.3148 , 2.1038, -6.7798, 11.6871, 15.5829])
c540 = np.array([0.0189 , -0.3332 , 2.2272, -7.1543, 12.0520, 15.3168])
c360 = np.array([0.0178 , -0.3181 , 2.1672, -7.0761, 11.6511, 15.8349])

curves = [c1080, c720, c540, c360]
labels = ["1080p", "720p", "540p", "360p"]
```

We can estimate curves intersections either with `np.roots` (which returns all roots, including complex):

```
np.roots(c1080 - c720)
# array([ 7.19666881+0.j        ,  4.11941032+2.23825508j,
#         4.11941032-2.23825508j,  1.14334481+0.j        ,  # <---- Selected root
#        -0.30297219+0.j        ])
```

Or with `scipy.optimize.root` close to unity (to only have the real root near to the intersection you are looking for.

```
def factory(c1, c2):
    def wrapped(x):
        return np.poly1d(c1 -c2)(x)
    return wrapped

optimize.root(factory(c1080, c720), x0=1.)
#    fjac: array([[-1.]])
#      fun: array([0.])
#  message: 'The solution converged.'
#     nfev: 7
#      qtf: array([-2.97761815e-13])
#        r: array([-1.40828365])
#   status: 1
#  success: True
#        x: array([1.14334481])  # <----- Selected root
```

Now we can assess it to all combinations:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
for (c1, c2), (l1, l2) in zip(itertools.combinations(curves, 2), itertools.combinations(labels, 2)):
    objective = factory(c1, c2)
    roots = np.roots(c1 - c2)
    solution = optimize.root(objective, x0=1.)
    axe.plot(xlin, objective(xlin), label="%s vs %s" % (l1, l2))
    axe.scatter(solution.x, objective(solution.x))
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
```

[image]

We see than combination 720p vs 540p does not intersect:

```
# [8.56875045+0.j         4.40845674+3.11694138j 4.40845674-3.11694138j
#  0.50716803+0.89895985j 0.50716803-0.89895985j]  # <----- No real root close to unity
#     fjac: array([[-1.]])
#      fun: array([0.15609229])
#  message: 'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the \n  improvement from the last ten iterations.'
#     nfev: 28
#      qtf: array([-0.15609231])
#        r: array([-0.00035679])
#   status: 5
#  success: False
#        x: array([0.69365609])   # <---- Not a root
```